# Functor definition in Haskell and its explanation in Learn You a Haskell is confusing

Tags: haskell

The excerpt below from '[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com)' says that `f` is used as the 'type of a value' in a function.

What does this mean ? I.e what does 'type of a value' mean ?

Int is a 'type of a value' right ? But `Maybe` is not a 'type of a value' ?

Are `Int` and `Maybe` both 'type of a value' ?

Would it not be more correct to say that `f a` is used as a 'type of a value' in the function?

So if `f` would be `Maybe` then `Maybe` itself is not any type of any value ? Right ?

Only `Maybe a` can be a 'type of a value'?

[image]

Comment: I think the *it* refers actually to *f a*, but you are probably correct that this could be explained better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that sentence was intended to be interpreted in a different way.

«We know it [`f`] must produce a concrete type [i.e. when `f` is applied to a type, say `a`, the result of this application, `f a`, is a concrete type], because it [`f a`] is used as the type of a value [the value being the return value of `fmap`] in a function.»

`f` itself is not a type of a value, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The text is basically trying to give a description about how to figure out the `Kind` of a type variable in a type class definition.

`f` is the type variable and you may think I can put any type here like `Int` but then when you look at the type of `fmap` function inside the type class you see that `f` is used along with another type variable `a` and `b`, which indicate that you cannot use a type like `Int` as `Int` doesn't take another type to give you a new type i.e its kind is `*`. Hence we can say that the kind of `f` is `* -> *` i.e it take a type and give you a type back.

The highlighted text says that `f b` must be a concrete type because it is used as a parameter  (`f b` as return type) for the function.

I would suggest you to read about `Kinds`

Answer (score 0):

It means that `fmap` takes as its second argument a value of type `f a`. Hence, the functor `f` is magging types (`a`) to types (`f a`). For instance, `Maybe` maps `Int` to `Maybe Int`. Also, `[]` maps `Char` to `[Char]`. Both `Maybe` and `[]` are functors.

Note that `Maybe` is not a type. `Maybe Int` is.